# Can I get magicEden's escrow program IDL?

Tags: idl, magiceden

I wanna have magicEden's program IDL.
https://solscan.io/account/M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K

I can see many transactions here, and what I want to achieve is to get listing price info from this transaction logs.

example: ) https://solscan.io/tx/5TUrNVydwNnzJvk8rUx4Msn5bQuTF4DrN97YKFqgMqbfTxhWjvuVb6rqy596BcwV4PvRU8FdP229vDHDb4qjr52o

There I can see `Program log: {"price":9050000000,"buyer_expiry":0}`, which means price lamports are 9050000000. Also There's are instruction data `66063d1201daebeafffc800a6c1b0200000001000000000000000000000000000000`

I wanna parse this data into readable data. Is there any way to parse it? I think getting IDL would make this work easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the price by analyzing instruction data. In your example, you know from the logs that listing price is `9050000000`. Using any decimal to hex converter, we can see that in hex this number is represented as `800a6C1b02` (make sure you are converting to **little-endian**).

Next, we can easily spot this number in instruction data (highlighted with brackets).

```
66063d1201daebeafffc[800a6c1b02]00000001000000000000000000000000000000
```

Is starts at 10-byte offset. Solana uses 64-bit unsigned integers for prices, so we will need bytes [11-18].

```
800a6c1b02000000
```

Here is sample code in Rust:

```
use core::convert::TryInto;

let data = "66063d1201daebeafffc800a6c1b0200000001000000000000000000000000000000";
let byte_vec = hex::decode(&data[20..36]).unwrap(); // each byte takes 2 chars, so bytes 10-18 will be multiplies by 2
let price = u64::from_le_bytes(byte_vec.try_into().unwrap());
println!("Listing price: {}", price);

// output: "Listing price: 9050000000"
```